# LLVM - Type substitution creates duplicate types

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

What I am trying to achieve: Replace every occurrence of `i64` with `i32` in LLVM IR.

Initially I tried this with a block pass. A block pass works for function bodies but not function declarations and global variables. I then switched to using a module pass, executing the following on every LLVM instruction:

```
void substitute(llvm::Instruction& inst)
{
    inst.mutateType(cast(inst.getType()));
    if (llvm::CallInst* ci = dynamic_cast<llvm::CallInst*>(&inst)))
    {
        llvm::Function* func = ci->getCalledFunction();
        func->mutateTYpe(cast(func->getType()));
        ci->setCalledFunction(func);
    }

    const int nops = inst.getNumOperands();
    for (int i = 0; i < nops; ++i)
    {
        llvm::Value* const v = inst.getOperand(i);
        llvm::Type* const tsrc = v->getType();
        llvm::Type* const tdst = cast(tsrc);
        v->mutateType(tdst);
}
```

where the `cast` function recursively casts a type to another type **by constructing a new type using** `Type::get`.

I have tried using a map to cache the created types, but a huge number of type aliases are still created, and incompatibilities upon module linking still persists.

However, this creates a huge number of type aliases, and the type aliases of the same structure are incompatible. For example, if `%18` and `%28` are the same type, then a function with return type `%18` cannot return a `%28`.

I've also read that `mutateType` is a dangerous operation. Is there a safer alternative?